# Google BigQuery Standard SQL - IN Clause working in BigQuery but not command line

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a standard sql query that I am trying to run in the bq command line tool. The query is executing flawlessly in the Google BigQuery web app (i.e. www.bigquery.cloud.google.com) but not when using the bq command line tool.

The query I put into web app is:

`` SELECT
 EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) AS ride_hour,
 COUNT(*) AS count_rides
FROM
  `aerobic-mile-205223.bike_trip_data.bike_trip_weekdays`
WHERE
  ((weekday_name_abbreviated IN ('Mon',
        'Tue',
        'Wed',
        'Thu',
        'Fri'))
    AND (EXTRACT(HOUR
      FROM
        start_date) <= 12))
GROUP BY
  ride_hour
ORDER BY
  count_rides DESC ``

("Use Legacy SQL" flag is set to False)

When using the command line tool, the syntax is:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) AS ride_hour, COUNT(*) AS count_rides FROM `aerobic-mile-205223.bike_trip_data.bike_trip_weekdays` WHERE ((weekday_name_abbreviated IN ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri')) AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) <= 12)) GROUP BY ride_hour ORDER BY count_rides DESC'
```

When I run it in the command line, I get the error:

> Error in query string: Error processing job 'aerobic-mile-205223:bqjob_r6cad99b97a68c167_0000016410bbe9d9_1': Unrecognized name: Mon at [1:176]

Any insight on why the IN clause is performing correctly in the web app and not in command line? Is there an efficient alternative? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) AS ride_hour, COUNT(*) AS count_rides FROM \`aerobic-mile-205223.bike_trip_data.bike_trip_weekdays\` WHERE ((weekday_name_abbreviated IN ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri')) AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) <= 12)) GROUP BY ride_hour ORDER BY count_rides DESC"
```

Comment: Thank you! What ended up working was the inverse -- double quotes for IN clause and single quote wrapping SQL statement. 

```bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR from start_date)) as ride_hour, count(*) as count_rides FROM `aerobic-mile-205223.bike_trip_data.bike_trip_weekdays` WHERE ((weekday_name_abbreviated IN ("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")) AND (EXTRACT(HOUR from start_date) <= 12)) GROUP BY ride_hour ORDER BY count_rides DESC'```